# So... I continue to be harassed by Caleb

Tags: support, moderation

[In Job 8:11-19 what ancient wisdom is Bildad quoting?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/39006/in-job-811-19-what-ancient-wisdom-is-bildad-quoting/39113?noredirect=1#comment76780_39113)

Soldernal? You see the crap answers on this site that are never deleted. Are you okay with Caleb deleting my posts "because he can" (tenure)?

I edited the post and added the bolded sentence and undeleted it. Please explain to him comments, down votes, etc. and take away the delete key from him until he shows some restraint SO I DON'T HAVE TO GO BACK TO MY POSTS TO SEE IF HE'S DELETED MY WORK FROM THE PREVIOUS DAY. I won't continue to waste my time.

UPDATE

I've often searched for my posts and not found them. Now I see that means that they were deleted.

Looks like there's no point in participating under these conditions.

Bye.

Comment: As per [What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867), if you have a problem with the moderator, please use "contact us".

Comment: @AndrewT from the highest answer there: 'If you have a problem with one moderator, it's faster for you to reach any of the other elected "Diamond Moderators" on your site as they have the most experience with your specific site'. I'm not sure if you meant to imply otherwise but it seems that the OP is perfectly right to raise issues here first if it is at all possible to resolve any difficulties locally.

Comment: *crap answers on this site that are never deleted* - ... as opposed to your half-decent and/or brilliant ones, which are: am I reading you correctly ? If so, perhaps the [Apostle Paul](http://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Romans_9:15,18&version=KJV&interface=print) could shed some light on this matter.

Answer (score 3):

Let me address a couple things from a moderator perspective:

1. I don't come to this site to harass you (or anybody else). When I do come to the site your posts don't even particularly interest me, the types of questions and topics I'm interested here are usually not the ones on your radar.

   That being said when I do come to the site I'm confronted with a big blue number in my toolbar --- the number of flags raised by users of this site for moderator attention. I usually work through that queue, then do my own browsing of whatever interests me, then leave.
2. Your posts are not singled out and flagged by any one user I see, the flags raised are from a variety of users. The common thread is that *your posts* have generated a lot of flags for various reasons. Part of that is just the math: your volume of participation puts you in front of a lot of reviewers. Another aspect of it is surely your proclivity to buck the system, whether that's the mechanics of SE sites or subject matter of this site. Some of these require intervention such as deleting posts that are NAA for the questions they are posted under, others have inspired moderator feedback we've given you directly, others have been rejected as moderators judged them non-issues.
3. The fact that some other poor quality answers on this site don't get deleted promptly is no argument in favor of allowing yours to stay if they do not belong. If anything, that's an argument for you and other experienced site users who see the garbage to *flag it*. Moderators can't read and police everything that comes up on the site, that's why *users* are tasked with moderation and given the tools to do so.
4. The issue of post deletion being silent is a red hearing. Yes it is true the SE system does not notify users of post deletions. If you want to post a feature request tho change that, go ahead, but it has nothing to do with *my* moderator activities here. Shortly I'm guessing the reason the system works that way is because *most* deletions happen in ways that most users are not able to change: largely in the form of old, closed questions getting deleted by the system. There is really no point in notifying answerers to those questions.

   In your specific case I have looked through a few of your recently deleted posts and don't see *ANY* that were silent deletions by moderators (me or anyone else). We always comment on them saying *why* they were deleted. Those comments *do* generate notifications on your side; the complaint in your post is factually inaccurate. I and other moderators have gone out of our way to make sure we've explained our actions.
5. In the event moderators make mistakes, there are better ways than this to deal with it. If a simple flag asking for a review doesn't work, you can take the case to meta here and try to convince the community that the action was in error. This post ... isn't really that.
6. In the specific case linked in this question I might have erred. On the day in question there were actually 3 answer posts that got flagged as NAA, and a quick read suggested the flagger was correct. I deleted them. Upon seeing this meta post I gave it a closer read and decided that in this case closing to reject the premise of the question was a valid potential way to answer. I promptly un-deleted the post. Your welcome. I still think it does a poor job of explaining itself, but that's not a moderation issue.

   Again if you think there are other cases where moderators are in error about their enforcement of site standards, feel free to make your case here on meta. If you can convince the community, moderators have to work with that. That being said I'd appreciate it (and you'd probably get a lot farther) if you made it less personal and stuck closer to the facts.

Comment: @LangLangC a moderator comment isn't removed from the ping inbox: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/158439/166851 (note that it is status-completed)

Comment: All I want is to know that my posts are not being deleted as a first resort by anyone at anytime. No one wants to give that.

Comment: As Jack [commented](https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3587/so-i-continue-to-be-harassed-by-caleb/3589?noredirect=1#comment6074_3590), that isn't how this site works. If you make posts that are _Not An Answer_ according to our site scoping guidelines and they get flagged, the job of all the moderators (and incidentally 10+k rep site users) is to delete them. Voting down is not the correct tool for the job, that is for posts which are in scope for the site but are, for whatever reason, seen as not useful or whatever. NAA posts get deleted, that's standard procedure.

Comment: So if I mark an answer as "Not an Answer" it gets deleted no matter what? Or do you review it and, if an a 3 second glance you don't see the answer you delete it? Because when you reread the answer you realized "I may have made a mistake". So how can I have assurance that you aren't going to do it again? "Take up a bad delete with other mods" is not a solution; not a regular basis.

Comment: @Ruminator Flags draw attention to a post, those who handle them (10k+ users & moderators) use their own judgment in what actions to take. We didn't suggest contesting a deletion with other mods (although you could do that by flagging, we generally recuse ourselves from such flags), we suggested you bring them to the wider community here on meta. That's the proper tool provided for the job and how the system is supposed to work.

Comment: @Caleb  So are you going to continue to lazily delete posts that shouldn't be deleted just because some hater marked it as not an answer or are you going read the post first and err on the side of caution?

Comment: @Ruminator That is a [loaded question](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loaded_question). I will continue to carry on my role as a moderator according to the guidelines of this site, my own best judgment, the tools provided, the input of the community, and the time available to me.

Comment: @Ruminator given that "Your posts are not singled out and flagged by any one user I [Caleb] see, the flags raised are from a variety of users", you may want to revisit your suggestion that these flags are generated by "some hater" and instead consider the possibility that this sentiment is shared with a broader user base.

Answer (score 2):

> Soldernal? You see the crap answers on this site that are never deleted. Are you okay with Caleb deleting my posts "because he can" (tenure)?

I'm not Soldernal but for my own 2c I would say that the moderators (not just the diamond moderators) are doing a pretty good job trying to stem the tide of problematic posts here on BH.SE. Some "crap answers" aren't deleted, but that may be due to difference of opinion on membership of that category, rather than proof  of inconsistent standards or targeted unfairness as you imply.

> I've often searched for my posts and not found them. Now I see that means that they were deleted.

I feel for you on this, and I know why SE have chosen to make this less than obvious when it happens — they want less conflict. That's not a good enough reason in my book; if someone puts time and effort into their contributions they should be notified on deletion. Of course this is not the fault of Caleb or the other moderators here.

Comment: This is the closest I can find to a feature-request: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80460/notice-of-deletion, but this is relevant too and has feedback from SE staff: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3394/question-deletion-notification?noredirect=1&lq=1

Answer (score -4):

1) BH.SE is ostensibly operating as a user-moderated model via a rating system but is in fact subject to the personal whims of a moderator. This is much the same as the USA's "Electoral College" where democracy is undone.

2) The votes are supposed to be "Up" when "This answer is useful".

3) Your policy of alerting the user to a deletion via a comment is not documented, nor does the evidence suggest that it is reliable. Instead it has the effect of: "Surprise! I deleted your post!" when I look at it.

3) My last post had no votes (as I had just posted it the night before) nor any negative comments. And you admit that on a second reading, "perhaps you erred". And this not a couple of weeks after I rebuked you for this pattern.

5) So as a moderator you frequently delete my posts without warrant, despite my calling you out on it and this is your defense? "If you don't like it, take it up with the other moderators"? You simply can't help yourself? You are a born over-deleter? How about you JUST STOP IT?

6) Being a moderator is not about "If I don't like a post I don't just get to comment, or vote - I just delete it. If I get it wrong, the real moderators will fix it". Not a solution.

@Soldernal, or whoever is in charge, please make sure he never deletes another of my posts without:

- **first trying a comment. This is normally all it takes**.
- then try a down vote
- then get prior approval or refer it to someone with less history as an over-deleter
- then delete, with a reliable notification. Other than that this is not a safe deposit of my posts.
- send notification to the user

Comment: I don't want an excuse, I want it to stop permanently so it will no longer be my concern that my posts are being deleted "by mistake". The errors should be on the side of caution.

Comment: No, your list of bullet points are not how moderation is supposed to work on the SE network. Moderators are not here to engage in polite criticism and encouragement (though they might do that in their capacity as 'users' too), their job is to respond to flags. "[The most common moderator task is to follow up on flagged posts](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/05/18/a-theory-of-moderation/)". Mistakes sometimes happen and then meta is the place to try and get decisions reversed. It is great that the moderators choose to comment on posts they are deleting here — that is above and beyond their duty

Comment: To paraphrase the blog post I just linked to: The job of moderator basically janitorial. The powers are used to selectively prune misguided or unhelpful posts, and guide the community.